# SQL Distance in Miles from Latitude and Longitude of 2 locations

Tags: sql, distance

Hi I have a Query that I get back a Latitude and a Longitude from OB and a Latitude and Longitude for PED. I need to calculate the distance between OB and the PED. I have to do this for multiple locations so need something simple to implement. I saw a STDistance function from SQL, but how can ant thought maybe there was a way to cast my lat and long to a Geography point but I can not figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

```
SELECT  DISTINCT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([Med_Number], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') OBMed ,
Zip as OBZip, County AS OBCounty,obz.Latitude as OBLat, obz.Longitude as OBLong,
PEDMed, PEDZip,PEDCounty,pedz.Latitude as PEDLat, pedz.Longitude as PEDLong,
'' AS PEDDistance
FROM sfo
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([Med_Number], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') PEDMed ,Zip as PEDZip,
            County as PEDCounty
            FROM sio
            WHERE 
              Office_Specialty like '%Internal Medicine%' 
              or Office_Specialty like '%Family Medicine%'
          ) AS sfp ON  REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(sfo.County, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') = sfp.PEDCounty
LEFT JOIN [e_ZipCodes] obz on sfo.Zip = obz.ZipCode 
LEFT JOIN [e_ZipCodes] pedz on sfp.PEDZip = pedz.ZipCode 
 WHERE Office_Specialty like '%Obstetrics & Gynecology%'
 AND med= '101'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what the datatype of the Latitude/Longitude columns are.

If they are numeric, then you can get the geography instances [like so](https://spr.com/how-far-geography-data-types-in-sql-server/):

```
DECLARE @OBpoint geography = geography::Point(41.878899,-87.636297, 4326) ,
           @PEDpoint geography = geography::Point(40.749014,-73.985317, 4326)
```

If the columns are text, you'll need to use a parsing method, i.e. [STPointFromText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stpointfromtext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)():

```
DECLARE @OBpoint geography=geography::STPointFromText('POINT(<oblat>,<oblong>)', 4326)
```

In the above, you'd have to compose the string from your `obz.Latitude` and `obz.Longitude` values, and pass it to the `STPointFromText` method.